# Does 'mleccha-desha' refer to the followers of Abrahamic faiths in general or foreigners in Bhavishya Purana?

Tags: puranas, tradition, bhavishya-purana, mleccha

http://www.mahapurana.com/bhavishya-purana/bhavishya-purana-the-prediction-of-indias-kings/

**From Bhavishya Purana we can find Krshnamsa words addressed to Baliraja**:
These demons should never come to Aryadesha (India) with you, all of you should stay always in mleccha-desha and eat the followers of mleccha-dharma.

Baliraja became upset hearing these fearful, terrible words.

Then Krishnamsa said: as long as I‘m in this world you should simply stay in your home,
after that you come here and do whatever you like‖.

**From another website it is found:**
https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/mlecchadesha

"Mlecchadeśa (म्लेच्छदेश).—a country inhabited by non-Āryans or barbarians, a foreign or barbarous country; कृष्णसारस्तु चरति मृगो यत्र स्वभावतः । स ज्ञेयो यज्ञियो देशो म्लेच्छदेशस्त्वतः परः (kṛṣṇasārastu carati mṛgo yatra svabhāvataḥ | sa jñeyo yajñiyo deśo mlecchadeśastvataḥ paraḥ) || Ms.2.23.

Derivable forms: mlecchadeśaḥ (म्लेच्छदेशः).

Mlecchadeśa is a Sanskrit compound consisting of the terms mleccha and deśa (देश). See also (synonyms): mlecchamaṇḍala.
Source: Cologne Digital Sanskrit Dictionaries: Shabda-Sagara Sanskrit-English Dictionary

Mlecchadeśa (म्लेच्छदेश).—m.

(-śaḥ) The countries bordering on India, or those inhabited by people of a different faith and language; defined to be any, where the black antelope is not found. E. mlecch a barbarian, an outcast, deśa country."

क्या म्लेच्छ लोग गैर भारतीय पैदा हुए हैं या केवल अब्राहम विश्वासी हैं?

WHAT ABOUT CHRISTIAN AND MUSLIM INDIANS? ARE THEY MLECCHA-DESHA?

In short, does the term mleccha-desha, and mleccha-dharma refer to foreign ideologies like Christianity or Islam, or is based on race/geographical location?
For example, would Indian Muslims and Christians be considered mlecchas in the context of this citation? They satisfy the desha condition (ie. they reside in India), but do not satisfy the dharma condition (they do not follow the dharmic approach to life.)

Comment: Trying to censor the Dharma Shastra won't help. You Team of SEH closed this Question without reasons. History and Shastras are not "opinions".

Comment: +1. This question is not opinion based, though it might be controversial according to some users. If it is indeed mentioned in the puranas, it can provide valuable information about the hindu respense to foreign ideologies and thier way of coping with them. (The reference in the bhavisya purana seems to refer to Muslim kings, as they were known for vandalizing temples, and killed cows publicly to humiliate Hindus, as cows were considered sacred by Hindus because of agricultural society.)

Comment: @IamThat. Please allow me to email you. There are things you need to know. And thank you for now.

Comment: The question is not opinion based at all. The answerer is supposed to show scriptural evidences and quotes from possibly the puranas, to explain what a 'mleccha' is. Is it a definition based on race solely, or is it based more on culture/way of life? For example, it is clear from the quote in the Bhavisya purana that killing cows and breaking temples seems to be characteristic of mlecchas, and it is this despicable character that causes them to be loathed in our shastras.

Comment: I didn't mean to be sarcastic. I saw your low reputation on this site, hence I assumed that you weren't aware of the features of this site/stackexchange network. Nothing wrong in that.

Comment: I didn't know you were an old user. Generally, reputation denotes the amount of time one has spent on this site. People, who have been using this site for long, generally have a higher reputation, as they answer more and ask more, in turn receiving upvotes.

Comment: @IamThat Hi Yash, please check your email inbox. Thank you. I have read your email. I have answered you.