# What are the mleccha-desha in Bhavishya Puranas?

Tags: puranas, dharma-shastras, tradition, bhavishya-purana

[Does 'mleccha-desha' refer to the followers of Abrahamic faiths in general or foreigners in Bhavishya Purana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/44453/22667)

My question relies on Puranas.
Puranas belong to Sanatana Dharma.
You call it "Hinduism".
I asked this question you closed it targeting that as " opinion based".
It is not opinion-based.
It belongs to Puranas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does 'mleccha-desha' refer to the followers of Abrahamic faiths in general or foreigners in Bhavishya Purana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44453/does-mleccha-desha-refer-to-the-followers-of-abrahamic-faiths-in-general-or-fo) Don't reask the same question. If your main question is wrongly closed, you can discuss with mods instead of keep asking the same. In any case, I have voted to reopen the linked question because it doesn't look like opinion based.

Comment: @Mr. Sigma moderators do not answer me. They are working hard to censor some people they think that are not seculars like them. Indeed my questions are not opinion based but Shastras or Itihasas or Puranas based. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question can be answered from the Puranas, it is not opinion based.

> What are the mleccha-desha in Bhavishya Puranas?

The "mleccha deshas" are lands outside of Bharata-desha (India) where Hinduism (Sanatana Dharma) is not practiced. I don't have the text of the Bhavishya Purana, but other scriptures like the Manusmriti say the same thing:

> [Manu 2.23](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145599.html) - But the region where the spotted deer roams by nature is to be known as the ‘land fit for sacrificial acts’; beyond that is the ‘land of the Mlecchas.’

The spotted deer that the verse is referring to is indigenous and native to India. The spotted deer is significant because it's hide is used in Vedic yajnas.

Comment: dhanyavaad mitra @Ikshvaku